# pycharm terminal always runs ssh each time why?

Tags: ssh, terminal, ide, pycharm

I have no idea what I set and now each time when I run pycharm then open the terminal, it'll run an ssh login to a server which I don't need it to run each time opening terminal.

Can someone give me a hand what I might have done to cause this?
Thanks in adavnce.